# Selecting multiple descended elements without writing full path

Tags: css

Is there a way to select multiple descended elements without writing the full path everytime?

For example, to select both **a** and **b** in the code below

```
<div id="wrapper">
<a href="#">Link</a>
<b>Text</b>
</div>
```

I use

```
#wrapper a, #wrapper b {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Is there anyway to select both **a** and **b** without having to write #wrapper on all the elements?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, nop.
Long answer. Since children elements will inherit what you set in their parent you can do this:

```
#wrapper {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

And, I think `<b>` is no longer used, but not deprecated:

> Note: According to the HTML 5 specification, the `<b>` tag should be
>   used as a LAST resort when no other tag is more appropriate. The HTML
>   5 specification states that headings should be denoted with the `<h1>`
>   to `<h6>` tags, emphasized text should be denoted with the `<em>` tag,
>   important text should be denoted with the `<strong>` tag, and
>   marked/highlighted text should use the `<mark>` tag.